# Can we have normal login and azure ad sso login in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, openid-connect, cookie-authentication

I have tried having a azure sso login in my existing application using the following link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet).

When i implemet it the normal login was not working. Since the cookie authentication used by default on startup.cs cause the following issue.

Can anyone let me know if this is possible in asp.net mvc?.

I have reviewed all but i doesn't have any proper documentation or solution to fix this on asp.net mvc.
Since all solution includes asp.net core.

Could someone help me out on this?

i have tried replacing the usecookieauthentication which was generated by default with the usecookieauthentication which was given in the microsoft azure sso documentation.

i replaced

`app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());`

with

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
   AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
   LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
   Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
   {
     OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
     validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
     regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
     OnResponseSignIn = context =>
     {
       context.Properties.IsPersistent = false;
       context.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;
       context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(timeoutInMinutes);
     }
   },
   SlidingExpiration = true
});
```

Comment: check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44362324/19991670) post if it helps.

Comment: i have no issue on form authentication. I face issue with the cookie authentication. @PravallikaKothaveerannagari

Answer (score 0):

*Yes, we can do normal login and azure ad sso login in asp Dot net mvc*
*Follow the below steps to achieve this*
*Create an MVC App with Microsoft Identity Platform Authentication*
[image]
*Select the dependency services*
[image]

*Able to logon with SSO*
[image]
*ADO Login*
[image]
*Normal Login*:
*For normal login users need to choose another account as shown in the below screenshot and have to enter the credentials*
[image]

Comment: Hi @RajeshM thanks for your suggestion. but i know it was possible in asp.net core mvc. my question is for about ASP.net MVC not core.

Comment: @SKZroST, yes we have for ASP.net MVC also here is the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1092710/how-to-implement-normal-login-and-azure-ad-sso-log.html